# sorting panda columns on ascending and then non 0 duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

i have a pandas dataframe that i am trying to sort

here it would be unsorted

```
col1   col2    col3   col4
  2       0       0    0    
  7    1207    3262    3 
  8    1212    3266    1    
  5    1246    3263    4 
  4       0       0    1 
  6    1232    3265    0
```

this would be the ideal sort:

This would be the expected result

```
col1   col2    col3   col4
  6    1232    3265    0    
  2       0      0     0    
  8    1212    3266    1    
  4       0      0     1    
  7    1207    3262    3    
  5    1246    3263    4
```

What i want to do is sort by col4, but if there is a duplicate, then use the row that has a valid value (non 0) in col2. the problem is that col2 may not be ascending or descending, just containing a valid value.

The only way i can think of doing this is creating new dataframes, but hopefully there is better way.

@ganderson's method ended up working for me

```
df.sort_values(['col4', 'col2'], ascending=[True,True], inplace=True)
```

Comment: can you post the expected too? i think of `df=df.sort_values('col4')` and `df[df.col2.ne(0)]`

Comment: You say in your edit "would not be ascending nor descending". Is it a _problem_ if they're ascending or descending? Or does it not matter as long as the 0 values are last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the provided example, this looks like

```
df.sort_values(['col4', 'col2'], ascending=[True,False]))
```

There is some abiguity in how you want the 2nd level of sort to be applied, but this should produce at least the posted output

Comment: You still sort col2 by its value ., *use the row that has a valid value *

Comment: I absolutely don't disagree, however with the sample data provided by OP this is the simplest solution I found to meet the criteria. If there were more detail than the part of the question you quoted, it might change the answer. In this case, it makes the `0` value last as requested

Comment: Lots of information lacking, but if allowed more than 2 rows per `col4` key, then this method would sort `col2` in a way, and the helper key method would sort differently (maybe unpredictably, depending on the implementation of the quick sort algo in pandas, which can be *unstable* and is the default algorithm for `sort_values`).

Answer (score 2):

You may need create a help key here

```
df['helpkey']=df.col2.eq(0)
df.sort_values(['col4','helpkey']).drop('helpkey',1)
Out[98]: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4
5     6  1232  3265     0
0     2     0     0     0
2     8  1212  3266     1
4     4     0     0     1
1     7  1207  3262     3
3     5  1246  3263     4
```